# How to query outgoing DNS IP targeted by local DNS server?

Tags: dns, networkmanager, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

How can you test to see which DNS ip your local dns server, eg., 127.0.0.53:53, targets without relying on wireshark?

I've tried multiple tools including `resolvectl status`. However, it prints both a global and interface dns configs and it's not clear, which external dns stub is selected for any given domain search. I'd like to see a result showing the routing outgoing from local: 127.0.0.53 -> 8.8.8.8.

Comment: You can use `tshark` (`wireshark` in cli)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how to do so "without relying on wireshark" but maybe it isn't possible. Seems it should be.

Answer (score 0):

To see which DNS IP address your local DNS server is targeting, you can use the dig command with the @ option to specify the DNS server to use. For example, to query the DNS server at 127.0.0.53 for the IP address of the domain example.com, you could use the following command:

`dig @127.0.0.53 example.com`

This command will send a DNS query to the specified server and print the response, including the IP address of the domain being queried.

If you want to see the full sequence of DNS queries and responses, you can use the +trace option with dig. This will print the complete series of DNS queries and responses, starting with the query to the root DNS servers and ending with the response from the authoritative DNS servers for the domain being queried.

To see the full sequence of DNS queries and responses for the domain example.com, you could use the following command:

`dig +trace @127.0.0.53 example.com`

This command will print the full sequence of DNS queries and responses, including the IP addresses of the DNS servers being queried at each step.

Note that the dig command is not installed by default on all systems. If you don't have dig installed, you can install it using your system's package manager

`apt-get install dnsutils`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Unfortunately, the first outgoing request node is still missing. In my test, I've set DNS to point to 1.1.1.1, however all that's revealed with the trace flag is 127.0.0.53 -> 193.36.xx.xx (root server), meaning I can't verify my setting is honored.